# How do I add file uploads to a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to add the ability to upload and store any kind of file, PDF, XLS, DOC, etc. What is the best way to do this in a ruby on rails application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is exactly what you're looking for.

[Upload files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files).

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend you to use [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [carrierwave](http://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) both are really good libs and work out of the box in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can also look at [attachment_fu](http://www.clarkware.com/cgi/blosxom/2007/02/24) rails.

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend attachment_fu as it appears to be unmaintained, and has been so for over a year.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked with two of the big players when it comes to file uploads. [carrierwave](http://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) and [paperclip](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip).

They provide a good solution for a common task with support for different storage alternatives. Both support filesystem and S3. Carrierwave also supports Rackspace Cloud Files and MongoDB’s GridFS.

I would recommend carrierwave because of one aspect where they are different to use. It uses a separate upload class that you mount on your model. This separates your code related to the file upload from the model code. I find this approach cleaner and easier to test.

Comment: WRT storing info in the object's atts, you can do this in Paperclip by defining a separate model for your uploaded object e.g. Create a profile object that has_one Image, using the image class to store the upload atts.

Comment: I now realize that I thought one thing and wrote another. What I wanted to express was that I feel that having the code in a separate upload class, and just one attribute added to the model, is a cleaner implementation than having four attributes and post processing code in the model.

You will still have to wrap both solutions in a separate model if you want to include it in a one/many to many relationship.